# Call stack size exceeded on re-starting Node function

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, timeout

I'm trying to overcome `Call stack size exceeded` error but with no luck,

Goal is to re-run the GET request as long as I get `music` in `type` field.

```
//tech: node.js + mongoose
//import components
const https = require('https');
const options = new URL('https://www.boredapi.com/api/activity');


//obtain data using GET
https.get(options, (response) => {
  //console.log('statusCode:', response.statusCode);
  //console.log('headers:', response.headers);

  response.on('data', (data) => {
        //process.stdout.write(data);
        apiResult = JSON.parse(data);
        apiResultType = apiResult.type;
        returnDataOutside(data);
  });
 })

.on('error', (error) => {
  console.error(error);
 });


function returnDataOutside(data){
  apiResultType;

  if (apiResultType == 'music') {
    console.log(apiResult);
  } else {
    returnDataOutside(data);
    console.log(apiResult); //Maximum call stack size exceeded
  };
};
```

Comment: You have a recursive function that has a base case checking for `apiResultType`, but you never change the `apiResultType` variable during the call?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `returnDataOutside()` is calling itself recursively.  If it doesn't gets an `apiResultType` of `'music'` on the first time, then it just keeps calling itself deeper and deeper until the stack overflows with no chance of ever getting the `music` type because you're just calling it with the same data over and over.

It appears that you want to rerun the GET request when you don't have `music` type, but your code is not doing that - it's just calling your response function over and over.  So, instead, you need to put the code that makes the GET request into a function and call that new function that actually makes a fresh GET request when the `apiResultType` isn't what you want.

In addition, you shouldn't code something like this that keeping going forever hammering some server.  You should have either a maximum number of times you try or a timer back-off or both.

And, you can't just assume that `response.on('data', ...)` contains a perfectly formed piece of JSON.  If the data is anything but very small, then the data may arrive in any arbitrary sized chunks.  It make take multiple `data` events to get your entire payload.  And, this may work on fast networks, but not on slow networks or through some proxies, but not others.  Instead, you have to accumulate the data from the entire response (all the `data` events that occur) concatenated together and then process that final result on the `end` event.

While, you can code the plain `https.get()` to collect all the results for you (there's an example of that right in the [doc here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback)), it's a lot easier to just use a higher level library that brings support for a bunch of useful things.

My favorite library to use in this regard is [`got()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got), but there's a list of alternatives [here](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143) and you can find the one you like.  Not only do these libraries accumulate the entire request for you with you writing any extra code, but they are promise-based which makes the asynchronous coding easier and they also automatically check status code results for you, follow redirects, etc... - many things you would want an http request library to "just handle" for you.

Comment: Thank you response. One thing I did notice that once first GET is returned then same data is processed over and over again like infinite-loop pattern. So loop gets stuck once it retrives first set of data. I was also thinkg aoubt using `setTimeout` setting interval to trigger every n-seconds.

Comment: @marcin2x4 - That comment makes me think that you don't understand that your looping is NOT doing another GET request.  You're just calling `returnDataOutside(data)` over and over with the exact same data.  So, if the data isn't right on the initial GET request, you just create an infinite recursive loop that eventually blows up the stack.

Comment: No, I do understand. Loop doesn't trigger another GET request.